# How to play video in Flash app for iOs (iPhone Packager)

Tags: flash, ipad, ios, actionscript, video

reading the [iphone packager's FAQ from Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone%3aDeveloper_FAQ#Can_I_play_H.264_Video_from_Flash_content_on_iOS.3F) i read:

> Can I play H.264 Video from Flash content on iOS?
>   Yes. You can play H.264 video from Flash content by launching the content in the native iOS video player. You cannot play back H.264 content directly within the application.

The question is simple, how can i play an H264 content in the native IOS video player ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.Video;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns_url:String = "http://617.gp.selfip.biz/mov/001.flv";

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = this;
function onMetaData(info:Object):void{
    trace(info.width, info.height, info.duration);
}
ns.play(ns_url);

var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.width = 360;
vid.height = 240;
addChild(vid);

vid.x = 0;
vid.y = 0;

vid.attachNetStream(ns);
```

Comment: the above worked for me, but when I removed the video, the audio would continue to play. I found I needed to call "SoundMixer.stopAll();" before and after removeChild(vid) to get the audio to stop consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i've found the answer [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/packagerforiphone/packagerforiphone_devguide.pdf)

> Video
>   Only Sorensen video and ON2 VP6 video are supported within an AIR application on the iPhone.
>   You can use the navigateToURL() method to open an H.264 video outside the application. As the request
>   parameter, pass a URLRequest object with a URL pointing to the video. The video launches in the video player of the 
>   iPhone.

Now i have to discover how to embed a video into my ipa and its url to load it using navigateToURL()

Answer (score -1):

Within AIR application FLV file format is supported.

1. First you have to convert your video with Media Decoder to FLV
   mobile format.
2. Import FLV format video file as embed video with Flash playback
   component.
3. When you package your application for iPhone that time include FLV
   file as attachment.